# Unable to insert in MySQL using PHP script in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase, android-volley

I'm trying to insert the firebase token_key into the mysql using php script by Volley library but can't able to implement it.I'm facing "AuthFailureError" exception.

I know i'm doing some mistake but can't able to figure it out.I'm attaching the code snipet down here,Please give me some suggestions:

init.php

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "*****";
$db_name = "fcmdb";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
if($con)
echo "Connection Success...";
else
echo "Connection Failure...";

?>
```

fcm_insert.php

```
<?php

require "init.php";
$fcm_token ='';
$fcm_token = $_POST["key_token"];
$sql = "insert into fcm_info values('".$fcm_token."');";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnClick;
String app_server_url="http://192.168.0.106:8079/fcmtest/fcm_insert.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnClick=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                final String token=sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),"");

                StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, app_server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("Error",response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i("Error",error.toString());
                    }
                })

                {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("key_token",token);

                        return params;
                    }
                };
                MySingleton.getMySingleton(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: whats exact the problem

Comment: I'm facing "AuthFailureError" exception in android code

Comment: AuthErr is not subjected to query failure in php mysql. Please check in android program. if the insert query fails in the backend please do a error post back in php mysql like for example $sql = "insert ****"; $res = $con->query($sql); if(!$res) echo $con->error;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey hi please follow below link

It will be help you

[This link for php with android](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-login-example-using-php-mysql-and-volley/)

Comment: Thanks for the link...I think there is some permission issues.